# Extract max(month-day) dictionary values per dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with multiple month-day values stored as strings for each key. The month-day strings are formatted like 'key':[ 'mmdd','mmdd',...] (see image)

I am trying to extract the mmdd values that have the maximum day for each month.(IE: the last date value for each month)
The values i am trying to extract are highlighted in red boxes in the images. Essentially i am trying to select one max(dd) for each (mm) value. But i am unsure of how to process the strings to achieve this.

My only idea right now is to create an additional dictionary inside each key, and this sub-dictionary will have months as keys and days as values, but i suspect there is a way to process this using string manipulation only. 
Please advise.
[image: mmdd values to be extracted]

Comment: Please provide code / text we can copy, paste, and run. Picture of code really aren't funt to work with. Also your dates aren't keys to a dictionary (at least not with what you are showing). Please show the given input and the wanted output as **formatted text**.

Comment: I never stated that the dates are keys - i think maybe you are mixing up my theory of how i can handle this and my actual input. Posting my script will not help since no one will have access to the source of this data (its read from a database and heavily manipulated before arriving at the dictionary you see here).

I am simply looking for a way to extract the values that are highlighted in red. 

The given input is the dictionary you see here, the desired output is the values highlighted in red.

Comment: What does help however is if you post your sample data as text that we can copy and paste rather than an image that we have to manually recreate.

Comment: @Marshall The main point is that we can't run a picture, and we don't know exactly what the output is supposed to look like. Please post some sample input and the expected output as text.

Comment: @wjandrea point taken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) that sorts each list of strings as integers in reverse order so that you can group them by month and then take the first one in each group.

Not sure exactly what output format you are looking for, so this results in the same dict structure but with lists that only contain the last date occurrence in each month.

```
from itertools import groupby

d = {
    'crtl': ['0419', '0525', '0526', '0816', '0819'],
    'mrc2m': ['0419', '0525']
    }

result = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    groups = groupby(sorted(v, key=int, reverse=True), key=lambda x: x[:2])
    result[k] = [next(g) for _, g in groups]

print(result)
# {'crtl': ['0819', '0526', '0419'], 'mrc2m': ['0525', '0419']}
```

Comment: Nice use of `next`.

Comment: You could factor out the call to `sorted` to improve readability. I mean like `v_sorted = sorted(v, ...); groups = groupby(v_sorted, ...)`

Comment: @benvc Thanks! This worked and there are a few things in here i didn't know about. Lots to learn from this solution, thank you.